# Where is debugging mode on Kindle Fire?

Tags: windows, amazon-kindle-fire

I want to connect Kindle Fire with Eclipse to develop apps but I don't see any entry like "Development" in "Settings". What's wrong with it? If it doesn't exist on KF, is there any way to do that?
When I open Manage on Windows XP, a yellow exclamation mark appears on Kindle. Is its driver missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always enabled on the Kindle Fire. You simply need to add the Fire's device ID to your `android_usb.ini` file so that the Google ADB drivers will find it. You can do this from the command line very easily with:

```
echo 0x1949 >> "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini
```

Then restart adb

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

And you should be good to go.

If it still won't recognize it then you may need to go into the "Manage" menu and uninstall the Fire, then unplug it and plug it in again (I don't remember if that step was necessary).

Comment: where is android_usb.ini?

Comment: @Emerald214: On XP is should be `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.android\android_usb.ini`. On Vista/7 it should be `C:\Users\<username>\.android\android_usb.ini`.

Comment: I tried this and followed your advice.
http://www.freerepairguide.com/kindle-fire-enable-usb-debugging.html

but the KF doesn't appear on device list (step14).

Comment: @Emerald214: So the driver and everything installed properly like in the guide? In your Windows device manager, do you see a "ADB Interface" (or similar) device?

Comment: Yes, I saw it, ADB Interface. I tried to unplug and plug USB cable then restart adb but nothing changes. It shows this error in console "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: @Emerald214: I think I actually had to terminate the `adb.exe` process from Task Manager once when Eclipse wasn't playing nice. I recall also shutting down Eclipse beforehand, but I don't quite remember. I'm not sure if that will actually work, though it sounds like now the issue is that `adb` is in some kind of weird state (but the drivers are set up correctly).